# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.CglibSubclassingInstantiationStrategy

Tags: spring

I have upgraded my Spring framework from 3.1.0 to 3.2.18.

Then I am getting below exception.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean 
>   with name 'myService' defined in class path resource 
>   [spring-biproxy-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested 
>   exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.CglibSubclassingInstantiationStrategy$CglibSubclassCreator$LookupOverrideMethodInterceptor: method (Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/CglibSubclassingInstantiationStrategy$CglibSubclassCreator;Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/support/CglibSubclassingInstantiationStrategy$1;)V not found

I did not make any code changes. Only altered the spring version.

Looks like spring framework removed class called `LookupOverrideMethodInterceptor` in 3.2.18 But in runtime, spring is looking for this class.

[Spring_bean_jar_diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLtOk.png)

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.18</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Show your full list of dependencies. These kind of errors only come when either your jars are corrupt or you are mixing versions of a framework (spring in this case).  I suspect the latter. Run `mvn dependency:tree` and check which versions are actually being used.

Comment: mvn dependency:tree shows newly added jars as dependent jars. But some jars are   added in the server class path directly, those jars may give conflict at run time. I am getting this issue in run time only.

Comment: This issue occurred due to corrupted spring jar. Once I put the new jar its working fine. Thanks lot M.Deinum